# Hide markers from google maps when click an external link and only show its corresponding marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do i change my center for google maps with a link and remove other markers? i have this code

https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/

So, i need to create a link for example

`<a href="#" onclick="variable='latitude = 21.0241839,longitude = -86.8148164,map_zoom = 6;';return false">Ventura</a>`

In this case the function must change google maps center to focus the "ventura" marker and hide the other markes and when the user clicks on

`<a href="#" onclick="variable='latitude = 21.0241839,longitude = -86.8148164,map_zoom = 17;';return false">Dolphinaris</a>`

the zoom will change and will hide every other marker and show only the ones of Dolphinaris

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `map` visible outside of `jQuery(document).ready`.

Create `var markers = [];` array.

When crating markers, add custom property `name` to it, and push `marker` into `markers` array:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0241839, -86.8148164),
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        icon: ventura,
        name: 'ventura',
    });
    markers.push(marker);
```

On click, invoke `resetMap()` function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="resetMap('21.0241839', '-86.8148164', 25, 'ventura');return false;">Ventura</a>
```

Inside `resetMap` function, set `center` and `zoom` to `map`, iterate `markers`, matching them by custom property `name` - matched one set visible, others set to invisible.

```
function resetMap(lat, lon, zoom, name) {

    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

    map.setCenter(newPos);
     map.setZoom(zoom);

   markers.forEach(function(marker) {        
       if(marker.get('name') == name)
       {
           console.log('match');
           marker.setVisible(true);
       }
       else
       {
          marker.setVisible(false);
       }    
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/1/

**EDIT:**

Question: *"is there any way to change smoothly the zoom and coordinates?"*

Yes, use method:

```
panTo(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)
```

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
>   less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
>   smoothly animated.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1

**EDIT 2:**

Implementing `panTo` is easy:

```
map.panTo(newPos);
```

instead of:

```
map.centerTo(newPos);
```

but as I have faced a bit 'flickering' effect due to hide/show markers that are close on the map, I have added some delay in functions invocation + markers show/hide:

```
function resetMap(lat, lon, zoom, name) {   
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    $.when( map.setZoom(zoom) ).done(function(){
      $.when( map.panTo(newPos)).done(function(){
        setMarkerVisibility(name);
      });
    });  
}
```

And showing matched marker is now executed with 300 ms delay:

```
function setMarkerVisibility(name){
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {     
   console.log(marker.get('name'));
    if(marker.get('name') == name)
       {           
          setTimeout(function(){ marker.setVisible(true); }, 300); 
       }
       else
       {
          marker.setVisible(false);
       }
   });
}
```

It looks a bit smoother like this.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/3/

Comment: Exactly what i need!! thank you, just one more question, is there any way to change smoothly the zoom and coordinates?

Comment: Yes, use `panTo` method - see my edit in the question.

Comment: I'm trying this way but it doesnt work, sorry for my ignorance, I'm new with js and google maps

map.setCenter(newPos);
map.setZoom(zoom);
map.panTo(latLng);

Comment: See **EDIT2** in the question.

Comment: Could you pleas help me with this one Ivan? thanks in advance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147822/multiple-markers-with-info-windows-map-error