# Multiple markers with info windows map error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this working map https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/4/ then i tryed to integrate multiple markers with info windows following step by step this tutorial http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/ so now i got this new version of the map https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/5/ but it doesn't work

Here the description how i think the added code works

This is the text for two info windows in order

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Ventura</h3>' +
    '<p>Ventura P</p>' +
     '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Selvatica</h3>' +
    '<p>Selvatica p</p>' +
    '</div>']
];
```

This adds a number to every marker listed before

```
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
```

And this one asigns text 1 to marker 1, text 2 to marker 2, etc.

```
 // Allow each marker to have an info window    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  I see a javascript error on that fiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

Comment: There is no `infoWindowContent` in your code. FYI - your markers array is already `google.maps.Marker` objects.

Comment: Found it, it just isn't long enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues with the code:

### First

Console error `google is not defined` caused by:

```
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

at the top of the file **before google js is loaded**. Move it inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

### Second

```
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
```

Why? They are already placed on the `map`, you just want to attach them `InfoWindow`:

```
 //marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 //    position: position,
 //    map: map,
 //     title: markers[i][0]
 //});
 var marker = markers[i];
```

In the above code is the root of your problem (info windows not showing up): you are creating **new** `Marker` object instead of using the existing one from the `markers` array.

### Third

> Console error: too much recursion

caused by:

```
 // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The issue with this one is most probably that `bounds` are undefined at this moment. Not sure why, but `too much recursion` is usualy caused by that. I have commented that out, so you will have to take a look how to pass valid value in `fitBounds`.

### Fourth

You have sintax error here:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
```

You probably meant:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9ugbc7h/7/